# Geo Fix not working in Android SDK 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to test an Android application. 
I need to send mock location to test this. I have registered for requestlocation updates(..)method (as follows)

> locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,
>   20000, 0, this);

Tried sending mock locations through Eclipse DDMS tab as well as telnet-ing from command prompt. telnet commands as follows

> telnet localhost 5554
>    geo fix 1 1

The application **works** fine (i.e. receives the location changed event) if I run using AVD Emulator using **1.6 to 2.1**. However, it is **not working** for **AVD Emulator 2.2**. I am using SDK platform Android 2.2 revision 2.

Does anyone come across similar issue? How did you resolve this?

PS. Extra Information. I have selected 'Allow Mock Locations' in all emulators (1.6 to 2.2).
Also, the following line is added in Android Manifest

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"

Issue still persists. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following bug report for a solution to your problem:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4036