# Unable to get latitude and longitude from android

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps

getLastKnownLocation always return null value. I have enabled geo fix and gps on emulator. However, there is no gps signal on the notification bar when running this on emulator. May I know is there any mistake in my code? Thanks.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LocationManager location = null;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.near_layout);

    location = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
    String bestProvider = location.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();


    Location loc = location.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if(loc != null)
    {
        double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(nearPlace.this,  " nice" + latitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(nearPlace.this,  "Location not available. GPS is not enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    location.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, ll);
 }

 private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {

     @Override
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(nearPlace.this,  " nice" + location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            nearPlaceDownloaderTask getNearPlace = new nearPlaceDownloaderTask();
            getNearPlace.execute(ANDROID_WEB_LINK + "gt.php?la=" + location.getLatitude() + "&lo=" + location.getLongitude());

     }
     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

 }
```

Comment: I would suggest executing `requestLocationUpdates` in `onResume()`, and make sure that you unregister the location updates in `onPause()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working, is because you have specified the following criteria:

```
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
```

Android will prefer to use network location over GPS, because you don't care about the accuracy. By specifying an accuracy of 20 meters or so, it will probably automatically invoke GPS.

To manually invoke GPS location updates, override `bestProvider`:

```
bestProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
```

You can really simplify this into two lines of code:

```
LocationManager locationManager =
            (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, interval,
            precision, listener);
```

Don't forget to unregister your listener:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check this out [geofix not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262542/geo-fix-not-working-in-android-sdk-2-2)

Also make sure you have mock locations allowed set in the emulator. Take a look at Pauls answer as well, which is why I was asking in comments what provider was returned

Comment: @davidlee Ok, well is it being fed locations? The lastknown call will return null if no fix has been established. Also what is the provider that is being returned by your criteria setup? Paul's comments are also true but should not stop you from getting an initial fix. Also see that a number of people complain about geoFix when using telnet, have you tried the direct DDMS approach just to see if that might be an issue?